# Jackson JSONArray nested in a JSONArray not parsing

Tags: android, json, jackson

Not sure if I'm using the correct syntax or declaring my classes right but it doesn't seem to parse a JSONArray inside a JSONArray.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my JSON file:

```
{
 "response": {
     "status": 200
 },
 "items": [
     {
         "item": [
         {
             "body": "Computing",
             "subject": "Math",
             "attachment": false
         }
         ]

     },
     {
         "item": {
             "body": "Analytics",
             "subject": "Quant",
             "attachment": true
         }
     }
 ],
 "score": 10,
 "uri": "http://localhost/v2.0.0/surveys/5511fa0b7ccabf820b08172a/5512d3de7ccabf820b081731/",
 "thesis": {
     "submitted": false,
     "title": "Masters",
     "field": "Sciences"
 }
 }
```

Here are my classes I'm using:

```
public class Thing
{
    public Response response;
    public ArrayList<ItemWrapper> items;
    public int score;
    public URI uri;
    public Thesis thesis;

    public URI getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(URI uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemWrapper> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ItemWrapper> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public Thesis getThesis() {
        return thesis;
    }

    public void setThesis(Thesis thesis) {
        this.thesis = thesis;
    }
}

class Response
{
    public int status;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

class ItemWrapper
{
    public ArrayList<Item> item;

    public ArrayList<Item> getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(ArrayList<Item> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}

class Item
{
    public String body;
    public String subject;
    public boolean attachment;

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public boolean isAttachment() {
        return attachment;
    }

    public void setAttachment(boolean attachment) {
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }
}

class Thesis
{
    public boolean submitted;
    public String title;
    public String field;

    public boolean isSubmitted() {
        return submitted;
    }

    public void setSubmitted(boolean submitted) {
        this.submitted = submitted;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    }
```

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: Is the json file correct? The items is a list of dictionaries. First dictionary contains item which has value as a list and second item a dictionary. Is this correct??